# Getting 'security error. checksum failed' in woocommerce paytm plugin

Tags: php, woocommerce, paytm

I am using wordpress 5 and WooCommerce Version: 3.5.4, for payment gateway i am using 'Paytm'. I set all the required filed as per paytm instruction, but getting error 'Security Error. Checksum Failed!!' .

Please help

Comment: Did you get the plugin from a legitimate place? I would not use what you have now as that suggestes that the one you have has been changed, and probably not for a good reason **There be dragons**

Answer (score 0):

Download the official Paytm plugin for WooCommerce which is [listed here](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Woocommerce_Kit)
Looks like you're using the one in WordPress repository which isn't official & hence failing security check

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with my WordPress website. "?paytm_response=Security+Error.+Checksum+Failed%21%21&type=error". i am using latest version of Paytm(https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Woocommerce_Kit) and WooCommerce